# Grouping array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, grouping

I have in my table the column, `infoanimal`:

```
RABBIT  || Male   || 15
HAMSTER || Female || 10
FROG    || Male   ||  5
RABBIT  || Male   || 40
HAMSTER || Male   ||  4
FROG    || Male   || 13
```

I have this at the following moment:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM experimental";
$query5 = mysql_query($sql);
while ($dados = @mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $infoanimal = $dados["infoanimal"];
    $pesquisa = explode(">>", $infoanimal);
    $num_pesq = count($pesquisa);
    for($i=1;$i<$num_pesq;$i++){
        $dadosx3 = explode("||", $pesquisa[$i]);
        $animal[0] = $dadosx3[0];
        $gender[0] = $dadosx3[1];
        $amount[0] = $dadosx3[5];
    }
}
```

I'd like to make the following:

```
Animal  || Male || Female || Sum
HAMSTER || 4    || 10     || 14
FROG    || 18   || 0      || 18
RABBIT  || 40   || 0      || 40
```

Comment: can you fix your formatting please?  Indent code with 4 spaces, and make sure it is preceded by a blank line.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  animal,
        SUM(CASE gender WHEN 'male' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS male,
        SUM(CASE gender WHEN 'female' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS female,
        SUM(amount) AS `sum`
FROM    infoanimal
GROUP BY
        animal
```

Comment: "Infoanimal" is a column into of my table, each line has this information animal||gender||amount>>animal||gender||amount>>animal||gender||amount>>animal||gender||amount>>, etc, etc, etc

Answer (score 0):

I would not concat those in one sql-cell, but store it in different cells:

```
create table animal_info (
    some_row_id int, 
    animal_name varchar, 
    animal_gender enum('Male','Female','Herma'),
    number_animals int);
```

and then

```
SELECT 
    animal_name as animal,
    sum(if(animal_gender = 'Male', number_animals, 0)) as male,
    sum(if(animal_gender = 'Female', number_animals, 0)) as female,
    sum(number_animals) as sum
FROM
    animal_info
WHERE
    some_row_id = <row of old entry>
GROUP BY animal_name
;
```

If tables get longer, think about an animal-table and reference it instead of storing the animal name for every shop or whatever is connected to them

Comment: some_row_id is stored in your original table instead of the long text, and you can even join my select as a subselect.

Comment: I managed to do the following code, but it appears as follows:<br/>
$animais = array($array);<br/>
foreach ($animais as $linha)<br/>
{$grupo[$linha[0]][] = $linha[1];}<br/>
foreach ($grupo as $x => $y)<br/>
{$total = ''; <br/>
$col1[] = $x;<br/>
$col2[] = array_sum($y);<br/>
$total = array_sum($y);}<br/>
echo $x." -- ".$genero[0]." -- ".$total."<br/>";}<br/>
I do not want the names to be repeated<br/>
Mouse -- Female -- 32<br/>
Mouse -- Female -- 77<br/>
Hamster -- Male -- 168<br/>
Hamster -- Male -- 168<br/>

Comment: Splitting and grouping the arrays in php will be much slower than grouping in MySQL, and if the data is coming from outside you can simply split them before storing.
As soon as a request comes to filter the data (for example, someone wants to see only female numbers), the problem gets even bigger.
Do you have hidden or good reasons not to use an extra table? Maybe that solves easily, easier than messing with manually split-data.